# No Target in Follow Path

Tags: animation, camera

I couldn't input a target curve in Add Object Constraint / Follow Path.
Nothing shows up in the list and the picker doesn't pick anything...
Any ideas ?
Thx
[image]

Comment: You need a path or bezier that the object can follow. Add one to your scene and you should be able to select it.

Comment: @rjg is right.  Try using a bezier circle, if you want it to move in a circle

Comment: Oh I see it doesn't work with a regular circle, only a bezier one. Many thx